# lottie-player: Is there any way to stop the animation after it loads?

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

I am using this `lottie-player` in html. I want to freeze the animation, after it loads for first time.

First I have used this,

```
<lottie-player
          src="./lottie.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
          loop
          autoplay
></lottie-player>
```

but, as I don't want a loop, so I remove that.

```
<lottie-player
          src="./lottie.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player>
```

Now, the problem is, after the first loads, the animation disappears.

how to fix this?

animation link: https://lottiefiles.com/web-player?lottie_url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets5.lottiefiles.com%2Fprivate_files%2Flf30_6e5k38rk.json

Comment: You can use Intersection observer API and after the person see it just set the loop property to none !

Comment: It looks like the animation ends on being hidden. So you have to tell it what frames to play. I don't know lottiefiles. But I would check the [getLottie()](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player) method of lottiefiles player. And then with the real lottie library you can use the [anim.playSegments(segments, forceFlag)](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web)

Comment: Hey man you can try after the animation completes add svg (from Fram when it is completed )  it would be much easier !

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you see no svg at the end is the end of the lottie animation shows nothing.

If you want to end the animation at a specific point preferably where the svg is still visible, you should use pause() method available. Please refer to [the lottie docs](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player) on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loop={false}` to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Setup loop property in options to 1:

```
loadingSuccessOptions: AnimationOptions = {
        path: '/assets/animations/success.json',
        loop:1
      };

<ng-lottie [options]="loadingSuccessOptions"></ng-lottie>
```